# how to add a script after showing 10 videos in a php loop

Tags: php

I want to add a script after showing 10 videos in my website. But I don't understand how to use an if condition for this. This is my php code which displays all the videos from my database. I want that after displaying 10 videos it display this script.

```
   <script>
     This may contain the code of chitika code. 
   <script>
```

This is PHP code.

```
 <section class="videos">
     <?php while ($res=$stmt_today->fetch()) { ?>
             <?php if ($res === NULL) { ?>
                  <section class="box">
                     <a href="" class="video-box">
                         <img src="" width="190" height="90" alt="">
                     </a>
                     <strong class="title"><a href="">Coming Soon</a></strong>
                   </section>
             <?php } else {
                     $immg = basename($images);
                     $imagee = "img"."/".$immg; ?>
                     <section class="box" style="width:100%; padding-top:2px;">
                     <?php if($images!=''){?>
                     <a href="video.php?vid=<?php echo $video_id ?>" class="video-box">
                     <img src="<?php echo $imagee; ?>" width="190" height="90" alt="">
                     </a>
                     <?php } else {?>            
                             <a style="margin-left:5px;"href="video.php?vid=<?php echo $video_id ?>" class="video-box">
                             <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $video_thumbnail; ?>/mqdefault.jpg" width="190" height="90" alt="">
                             </a>
                           <?php } ?>
                   </section> <hr>
            <?php } ?>
     <?php } ?>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your loop you just need a simple condition and a counter.

Here's an example.  This is a loop that runs 12 times using a `while` loop like your code.

`$i` is an incrementing variable (`$i++` increments it's value at the end of each loop cycle).  The if statement says if `$i` is equal to 10 then do something. In this case it echos "10 records reached".

Make sure that when you define your counter first (`$i = 1`) it is before the while loop starts.

```
<?php 
    $i = 1;
    while ($i <= 12) { 
        echo "record $i<br/>";
        if ($i == 10) {
            echo "10 records reached<br/>";
        }
        $i++;
    } 
?>
```

**So adapting that thought process to your code would look like this:**

```
<section class="videos">
    <?php $i = 1; // This is where the counter is defined ?>
    <?php while ($res=$stmt_today->fetch()) { ?>
        <?php if ($res === NULL) { ?>
            <section class="box">
                <a href="" class="video-box">
                    <img src="" width="190" height="90" alt="">
                </a>
                <strong class="title"><a href="">Coming Soon</a></strong>
            </section>
        <?php } else {
            $immg = basename($images);
            $imagee = "img"."/".$immg; ?>
            <section class="box" style="width:100%; padding-top:2px;">
                <?php if($images!=''){?>
                    <a href="video.php?vid=<?php echo $video_id ?>" class="video-box">
                        <img src="<?php echo $imagee; ?>" width="190" height="90" alt="">
                    </a>
                    <?php } else {?>            
                        <a style="margin-left:5px;"href="video.php?vid=<?php echo $video_id ?>" class="video-box">
                        <img src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/<?php echo $video_thumbnail; ?>/mqdefault.jpg" width="190" height="90" alt="">
                    </a>
                <?php } ?>
            </section><hr>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($i == 10) { // This is the new condition ?>
            <script>
                This may contain the code of chitika code. 
            <script>
        <?php } // condition ends here ?>
        <?php $i++ // increment the counter ?>
    <?php } ?>
</section>
```

If you don't want to include your null values in the count (your 'coming soon' videos), you can simply move the counter increment `$i++` up into the `else { ... }` portion of your condition.

```
<?php if (res === NULL) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
    $i++;
} ?>
```

Comment: This was the exactly i want. thanks for you effort. i really great full to you for this :)